# How to get a string in every cell split and entered into the worksheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a dataset with Excel column with skils and some of the Cells have more than one skills. I want to split the cells with multiple skills into each one per cell and then only keep the unique values. This is How I am currently trying to do it:

**I want to have the ability to input the range as well as the separator as I am trying to generalise the solution**

```
    Dim Separator As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim SplitArr() As String
    Dim NumofElements As Integer
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'Get the Separator and the Named Range
    Separator = InputBox("Enter the Separator Here: ")
    Rng = InputBox("Enter Range Here: ")
    
    'Split the String and add it to an array
    X = 0
    ReDim Preserve MyArray(X)
    For Each myCell In Rng
        If myCell <> "" Then
            SplitArr = Split(myCell.Value, Separator)
            NumofElements = UBound(SplitArr) + 1
            X = X + NumofElements
            ReDim Preserve MyArray(0 To X)
            For i = 0 To NumofElements
                MyArray(X + i) = SplitArr(i)
            Next i
            Erase SplitArr
        End If
    Next
    
    'Paste the array to worksheeet
    Range(Rng).Offset(0, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)
End Sub
```

I get an error in line 12, when I try to assign a name defined range to Rng. The error is

> Object variable or with block variable not set

which is what I am confused with since I have declared all variables.

Here's a working example for column cells containing the following:

- Business Analysis; Data Analysis; Networking; Communication Skills;
- Presentation Skills; Data Analysis; Problem Solving;
- Problem Solving;
- Problem Solving; Business Analysis; Communication Skills;

The Expected Output should be:

- Business Analysis;
- Data Analysis;
- Networking;
- Communication Skills;
- Presentation Skills;
- Data Analysis;
- Problem Solving
- Problem Solving;
- Problem Solving;
- Business Analysis;
- Communication Skills;

Then I can just filter them for unique values.

Comment: I think you need to put "Set" before Rng as it is an object ```Set Rng = InputBox("Enter Range Here: ")```

Comment: Sorry I miswrote that, Done :)

Comment: ...and then you will probably have to convert the user input into a proper Range object, something like ```New Range( InputBox("Enter Range Here: "))```

Comment: Do you have the right expected output here? Also, any reason why you opt for VBA over PowerQuery or some formulea? You are just interested in the unique values in the end?

Comment: @JvdV Yes, I am unfortunately restricted to using VBA for this and the expected output is now correct. Yup just the unique values

Comment: @Boketto Thanks it worked, I realised I have got another  subscript error in the code but thats fixable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something I came up with to condense your code a bit:

```
Sub GetUnique()

Dim sep As String, arr() As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

sep = Application.InputBox("Enter the Separator Here: ", Type:=2)
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Enter Range Here: ", Type:=8)
arr = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(rng), sep), sep)

For Each el In arr
    If el <> "" Then
        dict(Trim(el)) = 1
    End If
Next

rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)

End Sub
```